# Ruby Scheduling Clock Abstraction? Need 24 hour clock. Month irrelevant, Day irrelevant also

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application I need a 24 hour clock scheduler. Month is irrelevant, Day is irrelevant also but saving objects as datetime makes it hard to compare things.

"The Morning Take" runs from 5:30am till 11am EST
"Afternoon News" runs 11am till 5pm
"Tonight" runs from 5pm till 10pm
"Wrap up" runs 10pm till 5:30am

I'd like to be able to say

FeatureScheduler.get_current_feature
=> "Tonight" if its say 6:30PM

Running into issues getting it 'right' input as a datetime always wants a day and month and year... but I really only care about scheduling around a 24 hour clock... the day messes things up when I try to see if Time.now is between 5:30am and 11am for example.

Any suggestions for a scheduler that only cares about a 24 hour clock... doesn't use day, month and year in comparisons?

Answer (score 1):

Might be an elegant way to do this, but here's my take anyhow.

```
require 'time'

class FeatureScheduler
  def self.get_current_feature
    case Time.now.strftime('%R')
    when '05:30'...'11:00'
      'The Morning Take'
    when '11:00'...'17:00'
      'Afternoon News'
    when '17:00'...'22:00'
      'Tonight'
    else
      'Wrap Up'
    end
  end
end

FeatureScheduler.get_current_feature
#=> "Wrap Up"
```

Comment: I don't want to hardcode values. A 'Feature' will have a time that the publications editor can change dynamically. I'd really love a clock abstraction that only makes comparisons based on a 24 hour clock does not look at the 'day' or 'month' or 'year' when making comparisons.

Comment: Could you provide some more examples of input/output? I'm somewhat confused.